# Can not get entire table from html - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I was trying to get data using pandas from a wikipedia  article about the largest bankrupts [DATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_U.S._bank_failures) but for some reason the table was incomplete. I used this:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_U.S._bank_failures')
type(df)
len(df)
df[1]`
```

PS: I am using hidrogen to run jupyter at Atom. But that was the output:
[image: Output from Pandas]
Please explain what happened. I am new to Data Science and Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the whole table. By default, only some number of rows is displayed, hence the `...` signs in the middle. If you want to display all rows you can change pandas display default as follows:

```
# show at most 100 rows
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```

Note that this is a display setting only, the DataFrame contains all table data already.